# SCNProgram read from depth buffer

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scntechnique, scnprogram

I am investigating some advanced rendering in Scenekit, and what `SCNTechnique` and `SCNProgram` can be used for.

I would like to implement a multi-pass render like so:

1. First; render the full scene using the in-built PBR shader,
2. Second; render a single node with a `SCNProgram` which accesses both the colour and depth output from the first pass.

I know I can do something like the following with a `SCNTechnique`:

```
...
    <key>passes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pass_scene</key>
        <dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
            <key>excludeCategoryMask</key>
            <string>The bit mask of the node to exclude</string>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>DEPTH</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>pass_object</key>
        <dict>
            <key>draw</key>
            <string>DRAW_SCENE</string>
            <key>includeCategoryMask</key>
            <string>The bit mask of the node to exclude</string>
            <key>inputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>DEPTH</string>
            </dict>
            <key>outputs</key>
            <dict>
                <key>color</key>
                <string>COLOR</string>
            </dict>
            <key>metalVertexShader</key>
            <string>myCustomVertShader</string>
            <key>metalFragmentShader</key>
            <string> myCustomFragShader </string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>sequence</key>
    <array>
        <string>pass_scene</string>
        <string>pass_object</string>
    </array>
...
```

But I would like to use a `SCNProgram` for the object render, instead of specifying `metalVertexShader` & `metalFragmentShader` in the `SCNTechnique`.

I can't figure out how to pass through the colour and depth buffers from the first pass of the `SCNTechnique` into the `SCNProgram` for a second pass.

Does anyone know how to go about this? The documentation is difficult to piece together, and hard to debug issues.